# IIS FTP virtual directory problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I set up an empty directory, and had this as my FTP site.

I then added two virtual directories so that I could share them without having to share the top level directory they were in.

When I connect to my ftp site, I see absoluting nothing. However if I specify the full path then it will work in FTP, or via the command line I can cd to the directory without a problem.

How can I get them to appear as directories available for traversing when people conenct to the root ftp site?

all the virtual directories have permissions for IUSR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.  To get around this, just create real directories with the same name in the root.  The FTP clients will show the real directories, but IIS will serve up the virtual ones.

Here's a KB article for older versions of IIS, but this trick also works for IIS 7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247376

Comment: Actually, that trick no longer works in FTP 7.5 for IIS 7, so I'm dead in the water again.  S**T!

Comment: I had the same problem with IIS 10 on windows 2019. I did the same tick and now it is working. :]